# Depth First Search?

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, depth-first-search

> Forward edges lead to non-child descendants

- If a vertex leads to another vertex, by definition the second vertex is the first vertex's child. Therefore how can a vertex lead to a non-child? By definition a child of a vertex is something led to by it.

> Cross edges lead to neither ancestor nor descendant

- If a vertex leads to another vertex, the second vertex is the first one's child. Therefore how can a cross edge lead to a non-descendant if by definition anything a vertex leads to is its child?
- How is the source picked? How does the DFS algorithm know *where* to start?
- Does the type of edge depend on where the algorithm starts? For example if the algorithm starts at vertex A and and ends at vertex Z, a edge from Z to A would be a back edge. Hower if the algorithm started at Z and ended at A, it would be a forward edge. Is my reasoning correct? Does the type of edge change on each run?

Comment: -1 because I think lots of information is missing here. Where did you get those quotes from? What datastructure are we talking about? Can it have loops or is it a strict hierarchical structure? Where did you get that definition of a child? Is it from the definition of the datastructure you're talking about?

Comment: @EmilVikstrom I got the quotes from the book *Algorithms*. My data structure is a graph. I am talking about both cyclical and acyclical graphs.

Comment: The CLRS *Introduction to Algorithms* or some other book? I also think you should add this to your question because some people don't read the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If a vertex leads to another vertex, by definition the second vertex is the first vertex's child.

No; the "child" here refers to the tree representing the search space, not the graph which is "superimposed" on it to show the order of search. See the helpful illustration in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search#Output_of_a_depth-first_search).

Similar confusion for your other question.

The source is picked to reflect the *problem*. It continues until you arrive at an acceptable *solution*.

Let's say you're trying to see how to get from the bathroom to your bedroom. Your start node must be a bathroom then - the place where you are actually lost. You wander around the house, backing up and trying other doors, and when you find the bedroom (the solution), you stop. There are two graphs: one is the search tree; the other is the linear path of your search order. Actually three, if you include the problem space itself.

Problem space, with `<>` signifying bidirectional edges (all the doors in most peoples' houses can admit people in either direction):

```
            BATHROOM
              <> 
ENTRANCE <> HALLWAY  <>  DINING ROOM
              <>
            STAIRWAY <>  KIDS ROOM
              <>
            BEDROOM
```

Search graph - a tree (`->` signify a mother-daughter relationship; in a tree, they are normally regarded as unidirectional)

```
Bathroom -> Hallway -> Entrance
                    -> Stairway -> Kids Room
                                -> Bedroom                            
                    -> Dining Room
```

Search order - a linear graph showing how you traverse the tree.

```
Bathroom -> Hallway -> Entrance -> Stairway -> Kids Room -> Bedroom
```

In a BFS, given the same graph, it would be:

```
Bathroom -> Hallway -> Entrance -> Stairway -> Dining Room -> Kids Room -> Bedroom
```

The start node is set by the problem: "I'm in the bathroom". The goal node is also set by the problem: "I want to get to the bedroom".

In another problem: "I'm at a specific position in Othello. (start) I want to win. (goal)"

Note also that if I was lost in the hallway, I could still use DFS; you just translate the graph into a tree, and fix any edges as leading away from the start:

```
Hallway -> Entrance
        -> Dining Room
        -> Stairway -> Kids Room
                    -> Bedroom
        -> Bathroom
```

Comment: What's the difference between a tree and a graph? Isn't th tree just a hierarchal representation of the graph?

Comment: A tree is indeed a graph; but as you can see in my expanded answer, there are two graphs in what you're talking about, and one is a tree while the other is linear.

Comment: Riddler: Or again, I might have misunderstood your quote to mean something else; a descendant is not the same thing as a child. Every child is a descendant, but not every descendant is a child (notably, grandchildren are descendants, but are not children).

Comment: @Alexander: Oh, indeed. Any space in a connected graph *can* be a starting point. But for a majority of DFS problems, you have a starting position defined. Like in "find the bedroom from the bathroom" problem, or in "how to win this position of othello" problem. Also, DFS works on cyclic graphs just fine, as long as you remember where you've been to.

Comment: @Amadan, that was meant for Riddler. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Riddler, That is a complete different question which should be actually your starting point. You must understand the properties to know why a tree is an acyclic connected graph

Comment: @Amadan If your trying to linearize a graph, your source needs to be the vertex with no other points leading to it. How would the algorithm know where to begin in such a scenario?

Comment: @Riddler: As I said, normally the root node is set by the problem. Don't try to understand DFS as a theoretic concept; start with what the algorithm *does*, as it is very intuitive, and then pick up the theory. DFS is a problem-solving technique; you start from the problem state. You make a step, then another step; if you run into a wall, go back a step or three and pick another direction. The start vertex does not *need* to be a node with no incoming edges. However, that's what a root node looks in a *search tree*, which is not the same thing as a *problem space graph*. I'll sketch in answer.